# stop reason = signal SIGILL: privileged instruction

Tags: signals

My program c++ build in freebsd clang. But under function is program crash. Help me please.

```
Program block;


bool CHARACTER::DragonSoul_ActivateDeck(int deck_idx)
{
    if (deck_idx < DRAGON_SOUL_DECK_0 || deck_idx >= DRAGON_SOUL_DECK_MAX_NUM)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (DragonSoul_GetActiveDeck() == deck_idx)
        return true;

    DragonSoul_DeactivateAll();

    if (!DragonSoul_IsQualified())
    {
        ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_INFO, LC_TEXT("¿ëÈ¥¼® »óÀÚ°¡ È°¼ºÈ­µÇÁö ¾Ê¾Ò½À´Ï´Ù."));
        return false;
    }

    AddAffect(AFFECT_DRAGON_SOUL_DECK_0 + deck_idx, APPLY_NONE, 0, 0, INFINITE_AFFECT_DURATION, 0, false);

    m_pointsInstant.iDragonSoulActiveDeck = deck_idx;

    for (int i = DRAGON_SOUL_EQUIP_SLOT_START + DS_SLOT_MAX * deck_idx; 
        i < DRAGON_SOUL_EQUIP_SLOT_START + DS_SLOT_MAX * (deck_idx + 1); i++)
    {
        LPITEM pItem = GetInventoryItem(i);
        if (NULL != pItem)
            DSManager::instance().ActivateDragonSoul(pItem);
    }
}


lldb debug;

* thread #1: tid = 100852, 0x081086b4 game`CHARACTER::DragonSoul_ActivateDeck(this=0x31bbd000, deck_idx=0) + 388 at char_dragonsoul.cpp:90, stop reason = signal SIGILL: privileged instruction
    frame #0: 0x081086b4 game`CHARACTER::DragonSoul_ActivateDeck(this=0x31bbd000, deck_idx=0) + 388 at char_dragonsoul.cpp:90
   87                   LPITEM pItem = GetInventoryItem(i);
   88                   if (NULL != pItem)
   89                           DSManager::instance().ActivateDragonSoul(pItem);
-> 90           }
   91   }
   92
   93   void CHARACTER::DragonSoul_DeactivateAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it using a debugger (ie gdb /your/program/executable, then use "run").  Then do "disass"; it will show you the instruction that caused the crash.  Might be, clang emits code for CPU model newer than the one you have.

Comment: Thx for reply. The machine cPU i386 clang build setting generic cpu. Could this a problem?

Comment: The commands should be the same for lldb, except for the name of debugger itself.